# Why can't I get memcached item keys?

Tags: key, memcached

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 10000  
stats items
```

[image: stats cachedump 7 0]

Answer (score 0):

Memcached stores your items in a hash table and does not support listing your keys.

Note that hash tables are not designed for listing keys since it would involved scanning the while table (which is potentially large and mostly empty).

`stats items` does not list your item keys but [returns information about item storage per slab class](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt#L813).